# Selected index changed event of GridView fies Just one/two times

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    protected void GridViewBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewBooks.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex == GridViewBooks.SelectedIndex)
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#028fcc");
            }

            TextAreaBookDescription.Value = GridViewBooks.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;//The problem here is that the text is a long 700
        }
```

I think problem is that the text is a long 700 VARCHAR

It works If the text is shorter like a (name)??????

Cells[3] to name its It works here........

```
            TextAreaBookDescription.Value = GridViewBooks.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
```

i try ---TextAreaBookDescription.InnerText--- but it did not work

{i use UpdatePanel in .aspx  Just for more information}

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <textarea id="TextAreaBookDescription" runat="server" cols="20" rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have you used IsPostBack?

Comment: Not need in this case, my data up to date. 
How to give permissions to add text contains " '